# How to archive old nodes in Umbraco8

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

We're working on a news website, we have large amount of data, around 1 million news with 500 GB of media. we did some researches about the best practices, but there's lack of resources in handling this issue.

we concluded that we must archive the old news those are rarely visited by unpublishing the old years containers (2009,2010,...2014) to have a fast website in the backoffice and in the front, after unpublishing the containers we noticed that the Examine indexes files are still large and news nodes are no longer available via the original URL's because we unpublished their parents.

Please provide me with any insight that can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you unpublish the parent folder, the news articles will no longer be available, precisely because you've unpublished the nodes. If you unpublish any part of a path in Umbraco, the pages beneath it will no longer be served.

The indexes will still be large, because unpublished content is still stored in some of the indexes.

I know of a few agencies that have dealt with something similar to what you are trying to do, and they dealt with it by archiving off the old articles to Elastic or another similar external indexing service. The original articles are then deleted to keep the site fast. The archive page for the site then serves up the archived articles from the external index, rather than from Umbraco. This does however mean that the older articles effectively become read only.